# How setup Visual Studio Code for Run/Debug of F# projects/scripts?

Tags: macos, f#, osx-elcapitan, visual-studio-code

I have tried to use Visual Studio Code for run a simple F# script.

I download all recent versions as today. I install all the plugins at http://ionide.io/. Despite the nice animated gifs that show that it works, I'm unable to see how make to work the Build of code.

I create a .ionide file:

```
[Fake]
linuxPrefix = "mono"
command = "build.cmd"
build = "build.fsx"
```

But then, how install Fake? So, I do this from xamarin and install it. Ok, so now I get the build.fsx:

```
#r "packages/FAKE.4.12.0/tools/FakeLib.dll" // include Fake lib
RestorePackages()

// Properties
let buildDir = "./build/"
let testDir  = "./test/"
let deployDir = "./deploy/"

// version info
let version = "0.2"  // or retrieve from CI server

// Targets
Target "Clean" (fun _ ->
    CleanDirs [buildDir; testDir; deployDir]
)

Target "fakeBuild" (fun _ ->
!! "./*.fsproj"
    |> MSBuildRelease buildDir "Build"
    |> Log "AppBuild-Output: "
)

Target "Default" (fun _ ->
    trace "Hello World from FAKE"
)

// Dependencies
"Clean"
==> "fakeBuild"
==> "Default"

// start build
RunTargetOrDefault "Default"
```

Run the Fake:Build command and get:

```
No handler found for the command: 'fake.fakeBuild'. Ensure there is an activation event defined, if you are an extension.
```

And now get lost.

Answer (score 1):

install yeoman:  ">ext install yeoman" 
then setup a stand alone project with >yo 
and follow the instructions and say yes to paket and FAKE.

then >paket init 
and >paket install and it should work.

to get the > use ctrl+shift+p

For the Atom IDE you also have to install the yeoman npm package which I describe here:  http://www.implementingeventsourcingwithfsharp.com/?p=61

how to install the package is descibed here:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-fsharp

not sure you need it for Visual Studio Code

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

the usual way of doing this is to have a bash script that calls your F# script. Your bash script should look like something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
if test "$OS" = "Windows_NT"
then # For Windows
    .paket/paket.bootstrapper.exe
    exit_code=$?
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        exit $exit_code
    fi
    .paket/paket.exe restore
    exit_code=$?
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        exit $exit_code
    fi
    packages/FAKE/tools/FAKE.exe $@ --fsiargs build.fsx
else #For non Windows
    mono .paket/paket.bootstrapper.exe
    exit_code=$?
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        exit $exit_code
    fi
    mono .paket/paket.exe restore
    exit_code=$?
    if [ $exit_code -ne 0 ]; then
        exit $exit_code
    fi
    mono packages/FAKE/tools/FAKE.exe $@ --fsiargs build.fsx
fi
```

Now, you can define your build steps in your build.fsx script

```
#r "packages/FAKE/tools/FakeLib.dll"

open Fake

// Targets
// Dependencies
// Default target
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working.

That said, I'm almost as lost as you, the available documentation is not very complete IMO. Here's what you have to do (you tagged **osx-elcapitan** so I'm assuming **OS X**):

- get rid of the **.ionide** file, you only need it if you don't want to use the defaults. Lets stick to the defaults for now to keep things simple.
- make sure the path to **FakeLib.dll** is correct in your **build.fsx**
- Create a file named **build.sh** with the following script (make sure the path to FAKE.exe is right):

  mono packages/FAKE.4.12.0/tools/FAKE.exe build.fsx $@
- If it fails again, post the output error (click the OPEN button at the top for the FAKE command)

PS: Your question is two months old so I apologize if you know all this already.